# What does this mean in a Constructor?

Tags: c++, phantomjs

I am looking through the PhantomJS source code and I've encountered this line:

```
 Q_PROPERTY(QString frameName READ frameName)
```

I don't understand how this is correct syntax, it's even missing a semi-colon.

Here is the fine in question on the Github repo, in case you need to sift through it https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/src/webpage.h

Comment: it is probably a macro

Comment: Ah right, #defines are magical. I need to find where that is defined then

Comment: @EyeOfTheHawks: You can run the preprocessor and see what comes out the other end.

Comment: @KerrekSB Does that require me to compile it? PhantomJS takes about 2 hours to compile, according to its devs

Comment: @EyeOfTheHawks: You should be able to preprocess only one single file, which shouldn't take too long (unless you include Boost.GIL). For example, in gcc you'd say `g++ -E myfile.cpp`.

Comment: `#define` isn't magical. It is a simple text replacement, and in this case it will expand to something that contains zero or more valid declarations or statements.

Comment: @MattMcNabb haha i know that, just playin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a macro that the Qt Library defines to have its own Property System. It uses its own macros mainly because of being platform independent (its aim is not to rely on specific compilers/os). I don't think I can add anything not in their [reference docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/properties.html).

Comment: Thank you! I really dont know why I didnt look at their ref docs

Comment: Lots of incomplete or incorrect reference docs out there. Luckily, Qt is quite well documented.

Comment: Id say! This is gorgeous.  PhantomJS gives me a headache